# SSRS expression that can be used across multiple columns to hide a column

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I need some help on how to use 1 expression to use on multiple individual columns to hide a column based on the absence of data in a row within the column.

I have a report with > 100 columns. I want to hide individual columns that have 0 in the "Total" column (see screenshot). I know I can setup a rule on each column like

=iif(Fields!C1.Value>0,FALSE,TRUE)

but I am hoping to avoid defining a unique rule for each column to make this report maintainable. Is there a way to do this?

I would want to hide columns C1, C3, C99 because the Total.column is zero.

```
            C1  C2  C3  …   C99 C100
Total       0   67  0       0   172
Subtotal1   0   22  0       0   86
Detail1     0   2   0       0   5
Detail2     0   6   0       0   2
Detail3     0   0   0       0   0
Detail4     0   0   0       0   3
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the screenshot ?

Comment: My account is child-locked as a new member and I can't post screenshots :(